# Loading screen when fetching data via Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to start adding loading screens to my components when I'm fetching data from my API. I've made some research and tried my best, but my loading screen never disappears and I don't know why. I've tried to solve this for a while now hehe.

#### Action:

```
const setDoors = data => {
  return {
    type: 'SET_DOORS',
    payload: {
      setDoors: data
    }
  }
}
```

...

```
export const fetchDoors = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_DOORS' })
    const doors = await axios.get(`${settings.hostname}/locks`).data
    dispatch(setDoors(doors))
```

#### Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  isLoading: false
}

export const fetchDoors = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_DOORS':
      return { ...state, isLoading: true }

    case 'FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, doors: action.payload.setDoors, isLoading: false }
```

In my component I only have this:

```
if (this.props.isLoading) return <div>laddar</div>
```

And when I log it I'm always getting true:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state.fetchDoors.isLoading) // Always true
  return {
    doors: state.fetchDoors.doors,
    isLoading: state.fetchDoors.isLoading,
    controllers: state.fetchDoors.controllers
  }
}
```

#### Console

[image]

Comment: Do you have a React element representing a loading screen?

Comment: @lilezek No, not yet. I only have the `div` atm because I wanted to check if I got it to work.

Comment: Where are you dispatching `'FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS'`? I don't see it.

Comment: Something else that could cause it: You are `await`-ing `axios.get(...).data`, but you should await just the `.get(...)` like `(await axios.get(...)).data`. Could you try if that makes a difference?

Comment: @Denialos I haven't dispatched it because I am uncertain where I should put it after `dispatch(setDoors(doors))`

Comment: How do you expect `isLoading` to change, if you haven't dispatched the action that changes its value in the reducer? That's quite a mystery :)). Just dispatch it after your `dispatch(setDoors(doors))` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a tricky small error in that you are not awaiting what you think you are awaiting.

Compare your

```
const doors = await axios.get(`${settings.hostname}/locks`).data
```

to

```
const doors = (await axios.get(`${settings.hostname}/locks`)).data
```

In the first case you are actually awaiting some undefined property `.data` **on the promise** (not the awaited result) that gets returned from the axios call.

In the second case, which should work, you're awaiting the promise, and then you get the `.data` property of the awaited promise.

I reproduced the issue in the small snippet below. Notice how fast the first result pops up, even though the promise is supposed to resolve after 4 seconds.

```js
const getDataPromise = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({data: 42}), 4000));

(async function e() {
  const data = await getDataPromise().data;
  
  console.log("wrong:   await getDataPromise().data = ", data)

})();

(async function e() {
  const data = (await getDataPromise()).data;
  
  console.log("right:   (await getDataPromise()).data = ", data)

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

`dispatch(setDoors(doors))` should be `dispatch(fetchDoorsSucess(doors))` and should only be called upon a sucessfull axios call.

```
 const fetchDoorsSuccess = data => {
   return {
     type: 'FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS',
     payload: {
       setDoors: data
     }
   }
 }
```

In general, I have three standard actions for each ajax call, a `REQUEST`, `REQUEST_SUCCESS`, and `REQUEST_ERROR`. In the reducer for `REQUEST`, you should set `isLoading:true`, for the other two, you should set `isLoading: false` along with reducing any data you got back from the server.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I don't know why everything is becoming undefined inside of my component. When I log state, I can see that my doors have a key called `data` and it appears to undefined. Can you check the photo I've included?