# Redux state is getting undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I tried to add a loading screen when I'm fetching data via Redux and rewrite my promises with async await, however it's not going so well and when I log my `state` in `mapStateToProps` my data is undefined:

[image]

But I can see this:

[image]

And I have no idea why I can see my data there, but not when trying to access it via `mapStateToProps`.

Here's some code:

#### Action:

```
const setDoors = data => {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS',
    payload: {
      setDoors: data
    }
  }
}

const setControllers = data => {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_CONTROLLERS_SUCCESS',
    payload: {
      setControllers: data
    }
  }
}

export const fetchDoors = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_DOORS' })
    const doors = await axios.get(`${settings.hostname}/locks`)
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS', payload: doors.data })

    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_CONTROLLERS' })
    const controllers = await axios.get(`${settings.hostname}/controllers`)
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_CONTROLLERS_SUCCESS', payload: controllers.data })
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err)
  }
}
```

#### Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  isLoading: false
}

export const fetchDoors = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_DOORS':
      return { ...state, isLoading: true }

    case 'FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, doors: action.payload.setDoors, isLoading: false }

    case 'FETCH_CONTROLLERS':
      return { ...state, isLoading: true }

    case 'FETCH_CONTROLLERS_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        controllers: action.payload.setControllers,
        isLoading: true
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I wanted to show you my store because I'm using `autoRehydrate` and `persistStore`.

#### Store:

```
const enhancer = compose(
  autoRehydrate(),
  applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
)

const store = createStore(rootReducers, {}, enhancer)
persistStore(store)

export default store
```

#### Question:

So I wonder how I can stop getting undefined everywhere and continue working with my application. I am really grateful for all the help I can get.

Thanks!

### Update:

After @jonahe (thanks my friend) suggestion I've updated my code to this:

```
dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_DOORS' })
const doors = await axios.get(`${settings.hostname}/locks`)
dispatch(setDoors(doors.data), { type: 'FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS' }) // changed this line
```

But now when I log `state` I'm not getting undefined, but this (a `data object`):
[image]
Then an error because of the way my props are being layed out with my `.filter`, `.map` etc, and after the error I see this (no `data` object):
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your question! Your problem seems solvable. Could you please include,
1) The exact text of the error you're getting
2) A link to the problem reproduced somewhere like Codepen (That would be really helpful!)

Comment: @CodeWhisperer Thanks for replying. The problem is that there is no text of a warning, there's nothing. My state returns undefined and nothing is getting outputted on my screen. I can create a sandbox of some of the files I'm using, although not my whole application if that's alright.

Comment: @MartinNordström Is this a separate issue from your [previous question regarding this same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143683/loading-screen-when-fetching-data-via-redux)?  If so, you should inform people there that the problem is solved, by commenting or accepting a correct answer (if such an answer exists). You can also [post an answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it, for documentation purposes (and so that people who read in the future can learn from it and don't have to waste time trying to solve a solved problem).

Comment: @jonahe Hello! Yes I understand, but unfortunately that problem has not been resolved. As soon as this is solved I will updated my previous question.

Comment: It appears you are using redux-thunk. But your thunk is returning an async function, which I'm not 100% convinced the api supports. Instead move the async part inside the thunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer for `FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS` depends on there being a `payload.setDoors` property. That property is indeed there in the action creator function you have defined:

```
const setDoors = data => {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS',
    payload: {
      setDoors: data
    }
  }
}
```

BUT your're not using that action creator. You are dispatching `FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS` with this code:

```
dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS', payload: doors.data })
```

You can see this in the screenshot of the dispatched action as well. The data is there as `payload`, but the payload doesn't have the expected structure. Payload is an array, but the reducer expects payload to be an object with a `.setDoors`property.

(And there seems to be an analogous issue with `FETCH_CONTROLLERS_SUCCESS`).

Comment: Oh yeah I think I understand what you are talking about. I removed; `dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS', payload: doors.data })`, with `dispatch(setDoors(doors.data), { type: 'FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS' })` and I can see the data in my console, BUT. When I log state I can see my data inside of a `data` object, then my code errors because of how I typed my `props` with `.map()` etc, but after the error I can see my data NOT in a `data` object. Please see the new images in my question.

Comment: I've updated the question and upvoted your answer! Thanks.

Comment: Havent looked at your updated question yet. But the `setDoors` function already returns an object with the type and all that. So this is how you're supposed to use it:   dispatch(setDoors(doors.data)) .

Comment: If you console.log the data directly after you await it, does the structure of the response look like you expect? It seems to have a `'.data'` but maybe  there's an even deeper structure (like for example  `data.data`)  where you are only interested in keeping the inner part and send it to your action creator. So depending on your finding, the code might become `dispatch(setDoors(doors.data.data))` .  or something similar.

Comment: Dispatch should only take 1 argument, not 2. Although, I'm not convinced that will fix your missing data here